# Is there an option to select ALL from the choice parameter in Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile which takes parmeters and have two choices

```
 choice(choices: ['APP1', 'APP2'], description: 'Please choose your application', name: 'APP')
```

is there a way where I can select the above two applications (for ex choice ALL) where if I select All choice i shoul be able to pass those two values to a shell script one by one I dont want to use the same shell script twice

```
sh """aws deploy push --application-name \"${params.APP}\"""
```

I have seen the **Active choice plugin** and **extensible choice** but none of them have this option to select ALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a other way to do this You can use transpose and pass the items in your list simultaneously to the shell script

Ref : [pass items to shell script using transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217148/passing-items-in-two-lists-simultaneoulsy-in-each-loop-jenkinsfile)