# passing items in two lists simultaneoulsy in each loop Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a list `foo = ['tea',''sugar','milk']` and `col = ['black','white','pink']` what I am trying to do is nested loop

```
def foo = ['tea','sugar','milk']
def col = ['black','white','pink']

[foo, col].transpose().each { x, y ->
   sh """aws deploy push --application-name "${x}" --source "${y}" """
}
```

Desired Result

```
--application-name "tea" --source "black" 
--application-name "sugar" --source "white" 
--application-name "milk" --source "pink"
```

the result I am getting

```
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
--application-name "[tea, black]" --source "null" 
[Pipeline] echo
--application-name "[sugar, white]" --source "null" 
[Pipeline] echo
--application-name "[milk, pink]" --source "null" 
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
```

I want the list items in **foo** and **col** to be injected one by one  to the above shell script
Is there a way where we can pass both list items at once to the above shell script

Ref [Nested `each` loops in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207649/nested-each-loops-in-groovy)

Can we do something like `(foo,col).each`

or maybe using for loop `for(x in foo && y in col)`

Ref my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('hello'){
        steps{
        script{ 
        def foo = ['tea','sugar','milk']
        def col = ['black','white','pink']

        [foo, col].transpose().each { x, y ->
        sh """aws deploy push --application-name "${x}" --source "${y}" """
        //echo """--application-name \"${x}\" --source \"${y}\" """
        }
      }
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: For simplicity pupose I am using echo instead of sh in jenkinsfile because if we use sh we get command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe transpose is the method you are after, to pair up the two lists, then you can iterate through the result:

```
[foo, col].transpose().each { x, y ->
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**:

This is what I was aiming at. Note that some of the parameters are removed for brevity

```
def foo = ['tea','sugar','milk']
def col = ['black','white','pink']

[foo, col].transpose().each { x, y ->
   println """--application-name "${x}" --source "${y}" """
}
```

results

```
--application-name "tea" --source "black" 
--application-name "sugar" --source "white" 
--application-name "milk" --source "pink"
```

Comment: Thansk for the quick reply @tim_yates but unfortunately the result I am getting is `--application-name '[tea, black]'`  and for `--source null` I need to get `--application-name tea` and `--source black` and for the next loop i need to get `--application-name suagr` and `--source white` and so on

Comment: @startprogramming Please check the update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro this works fine I have checked in tutoriaslpoint but when you execute in Jenkins its still the same as my previous comment and I want to execute in **shell** script not just **echo** or **println**

Comment: And `sh """aws deploy push --application-name "$x" --source "$y" """` doesn't work?

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks, No its the same issue I have updated my question as I said I am getting `--application-name "[tea, black]" --source "null"` when you run in jenkins

Comment: Try: `[foo, col].transpose().each { x ->
   sh """aws deploy push --application-name "${x[0]}" --source "${x[1]}" """
}`

Comment: @tim_yates Wow.. Thanks a lot Tim worked like a charm was picking my hair out for this ..